# How are database datatypes returned in DataColumn class?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, sqldatatypes, datacolumn

I have searched and found surprisingly few results. I found that there is some datatype property for DataColums, but when retrieving data from a SQL server database, what is the datatype of whatever is retrieved? I'm working with a `SqlDataAdapter` to fill a `DataTable`. To get the values, I work as follows:

```
DataTable dtt = Database.get(SQLString); //pseudo-code
string value = dtt.Rows[0][0]; //Or is this a string?
```

So what is in `dtt.Rows[0][0]` if the database column datatype is bigint, int, date or bit?
Do I need to convert them to string first and then convert them to other datatypes I require?

Comment: please post your table schema, and you should acces columns by name, and it's much easier with Field and SetField DataRow extensions methods

Comment: Setting a breakpoint on the second line, then inspecting the value in the debugger could answer your question quite quickly.

Comment: @AntonioBakula What do you mean by schema? Sorry, I'm pretty new to databases... But I doubt you need to know my schema. I just want to know if the datatype is filled in and how I can best convert them to C# datatypes...

Comment: by table schema I meanted your SQL and type of used fields in database, type is defined in database

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You're right, but I was hoping to do it without trial-and-error... I hoped that was a valid reason for asking a suestion on SO, so that I don't have to fiddle...

Comment: @AntonioBakula We use the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` assembly and we have used bigint, int, date and bit but also nchar, etc... On columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it depends how is defined in database, for example let's say that you have this table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [Birthday] [datetime])
```

then you can access first row like that :

```
DataTable dtt = Database.get("Select * from Test"); //pseudo-code
DataRow rw = dtt.Rows[0];
int id = rw.Field<int>("ID");
string name = rw.Field<string>("Name");
DateTime dt = rw.Field<DateTime>("Birthday");
```

or

```
DataTable dtt = Database.get("Select * from Test"); //pseudo-code
int id = (int) dtt[0]["ID"];
string name = (string) dtt[0]["Name"];
DateTime dt = (DateTime) dtt[0]["Birthday")];
```

Answer (score 2):

> So what is in `dtt.Rows[0][0]` if the database column datatype is `bigint`, `int`, `date` or `bit`?

A boxed `Int64`, a boxed `Int32`, a boxed `DateTime` and a boxed `Boolean`, respectively. This is why the return type of this expression is `Object` - so that it can return a value of an appropriate type. All you need to do (knowing what type should have been returned) is insert a cast/unbox - unless you wish to continue treating them all as `Object`s.

And I agree with Antonio's comment - it would be preferable to be accessing columns by name rather than by ordinal position - you can either use the overloaded operators which accept `string`s rather than `int`s, or at the least, use [`IndexOf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bda1yss.aspx) to look up the columns ordinal position at runtime.